# Expected Value Largest Eigenvalue of a Random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

For a symmetric matrix whose entries are chosen uniformly at random $[-1,1]$ how do I find the expected value of the maximum eigenvalue of the matrix. As far as I understand finding this expected value is a non-trivial problem. Is there anyway to see how this expected value scales with the size of the matrix?

Comment: For $1 \times 1$ matrices the exact answer is 0. =)

Comment: I see. I just wanted to know if it will blow up with the size of the matrix

Comment: For $2 \times 2$ $[A \: B; B \: D]$ the max eigenvalue is $L=A+D + \sqrt{(A-D)^2 + 4B^2}$ which has expected value $$E[L] = E\left[\sqrt{(A-D)^2+4B^2}\right]=\frac{1}{8}\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{(x-y)^2+4z^2} \: dx\: dy \: dz \approx 1.30351$$